# Ubuntu 16.04 : Nvidia couldn't find registry key file

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, bumblebee

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 with Nvidia 940M. I have installed nvidia-prime, bumblebee and the nvidia drivers (370). On using the command `nvidia-settings`, I get:

```
** Message: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? yes

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should
       have been installed along with this driver at
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
       application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
       prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
       Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
```

What should I do to remove these errors?

Comment: With bumblebee nvidia-settings should be used with some parameters to work.

Comment: And also nvidia-prime is not compatible with bumblebee.

Comment: What is the solution then? I dont know anything about this.

Comment: Remove bumblebee.